# Webpack - Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: webpack, request, ajv

I am getting three warning messages when importing `request` in a barebone webpack project. A minimal example to reproduce the bug is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Oduig/webpackfiddle) (run `npm install` and `npm start`).

`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

How can I get rid of this warning?

---

More information:

Webpack tries to resolve `require` calls statically to make a minimal bundle. When a library uses variables or expressions in a require call (such as `require('' + 'nodent')` in [these lines](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/c19c02aa045f8d8fe55852b4303899f82e6de381/lib/async.js#L78) of `ajv`), Webpack cannot resolve them statically and imports the entire package.

My rationale is that this dynamic import is not desirable in production, and code is best kept warning-free. That means I want any solution that resolves the problem. E.g.:

1. Manually configure webpack to import the required libraries and prevent the warnings from occurring.
2. Adding a `hack.js` file to my project that overrides the require calls in some way.
3. Upgrading my libraries. `ajv-5.0.1-beta.3` has a fix that silences the warnings. However, if I want to use it, I have to wait until it is released, and then until `har-validator` and `request` release subsequent updates. If there is a way to force `har-validator` to use the beta version of `ajv`, that would solve my problem.
4. Other

Comment: 1. https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/117#issuecomment-198328830 2. I don't think it'll work 3. you'll have to wait a bit.

Comment: @esp: that github comment seems to be what I'm looking for, but it doesn't silence the warnings. If I change it to `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/async/, /ajv/)`, two out of three warnings are gone but webpack `Cannot find module "../async"`. Any idea about the proper magic value to make it work?

Comment: The link to the github code example is broken. Pls put code directly into the question.

Comment: For those seeing this after writing dynamic, expression-based imports in your own code, you can bypass the warning with [something like](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8341#issuecomment-436550381) `import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ "http://example.com/cdn/file.js")`. This is not a solution, but a workaround.

Comment: @Ninjakannon that should be made into the answer

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Solved with `npm install request@2.79.0 --save`

According to the authors of `ajv`, the issue will likely be resolved in the latest version of `request` in a few weeks' time.

Comment: @maembe try `npm remove request` and reinstall, then in `package.json` remove the `^` before the version number. If you leave the `^`, the package may be updated after an `npm update` and the warning reappears.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  But the suggestion by @DhirendraNk in a different answer below, which is to replacing the webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin worked for me.

Comment: for those that follow - request package is now depreciated.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, but don't you know how to resolve it today? I get ajv as the dependency of eslint -> @eslint/eslintrc (2.1.0). Although there is no "request" on my lock file. Probably the best answer is outdated

Answer (score 29):

Encountered it while lazy loading a resource

```
const asset = 'config.json';
lazy(async () => await import(asset));
```

Solved it by changing the import parameter to string explicitly

```
const asset = 'config.json';
lazy(async () => await import(`${asset}`));
```

Comment: Perfect for my use case (static testing for an eventual API integration), thankyou.

Answer (score 11):

Replace this

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
        helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
        {} // a map of your routes
    ),
```

with this-

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin( /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/, root('./src'), {} )
```

Comment: This does work. It would be nice for a more in-depth explanation as to why the regular expression change fixes this issue.

Comment: This works for me, it's been annoying to see the warning, thanks.

Comment: does anyone knows where to find this code? I am unable to find the code to replace.

Comment: This works because you are telling the `System.Import` function where to find source code in the `node_modules` folder. The path changes depending on the Angular version you are using. It should be handled better by the Angular team, hopefully it has already been.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 6):

This warning can be linked to packages injections in (dependancies or devDependencies).

If the problem suddenly appears, check the last modification in your package.json.

Consider removing package-lock.json if you plan to relaunch an `npm install`.

Answer (score 2):

I got this when attemting a 'procedural' lazy load, webpack needs to understand the import statements at compile time.

```js
//BAD - webpack can't tell this is constant
const pages = ['privacy-policy', 'terms-of-service']
  .map(name => 
    lazy(() => import(`./${name}`)))


//OK - webpack can tell this is constant
const names = ['privacy-policy', 'terms-of-service']
const pages = names.map((name, index) => 
    lazy(() => import(`./${names[index]}`)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this in Angular when I imported EventEmitter from 'protractor' by accident. I blame my IDE for even suggesting it!

It should be imported from core:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same warnnig working with with typeorm and nextjs.
I silenced it by doing using the code from [here](https://typeorm.io/faq#how-to-use-webpack-for-the-backend)

```
const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        //ignore the drivers you don't want. This is the complete list of all drivers -- remove the suppressions for drivers you want to use.
        new FilterWarningsPlugin({
            exclude: [/mongodb/, /mssql/, /mysql/, /mysql2/, /oracledb/, /pg/, /pg-native/, /pg-query-stream/, /react-native-sqlite-storage/, /redis/, /sqlite3/, /sql.js/, /typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver/]
        })
    ]
};
```

I added a regex like this to the exclude array above.

```
/Critical dependency/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered at the same problem. Firstly I've gave up, but now a have the following solution.

webpack.config.js

```
var entries = {
app: [
    pathToDefaultAssets+'js/app.js',
    pathToDefaultAssets+'scss/index.scss'
],
dev: [
    pathToDefaultAssets+'js/dev.js'
],
...
```

app.js and index.scss are bootstraps for your project.

and the main part:

dev.js

```
import { a } from './module-one.js';
```

module-one.js

```
var a = function () {
    return 'a';
};

export { a }
```

I your app.js you can use now:

```
var src = 'one';
document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
    import('./module-'+src+'.js').then(function (module) {
        console.log(module.a());
    });
});
```

And that it is!