# How to get rid of warning "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, warnings

Out of the blue this warning started appearing in console and I don't know how to get rid of it.

[image]

This is the main part of my ./app/src/routes.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import store, { history } from './store';
import AppContainer from './containers/AppContainer'; // eslint-disable-line
import * as Pages from './pages';
import AppHolder from './containers/AppHolderContainer/index';
import { isAuthorized } from './network';

const RouterApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
        <Route path="login" component={Pages.LoginPage} />
        <IndexRoute component={Pages.LoginPage} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="app" component={AppHolder} >
        <IndexRoute component={Pages.EmployeePage} />
        <Route path="reservationmap" component={Pages.EmployeePage} />
        <Route path="manager" component={Pages.ManagerPage} />
        <Route path="permissions" component={Pages.AdminPage} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={Pages.LoginPage} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

export default RouterApp;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908116/webpack-critical-dependency-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression

Comment: I have seen almost every "question" but I don't know how to help myself.