# npm warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I created a library for vue and publish on npm, when I install it on my project and run the server I get an warning that I don't know how to fix. The lib is working, but I want to remove the warning.

Warning:

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                          11:57:34 AM

 warning  in ./node_modules/store-module-test/dist/storeModule.js

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

repository: https://github.com/DouglasCalora/store-module-test npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/store-module-test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908116/webpack-critical-dependency-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression Check that question