# Export API from CLI package

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, monorepo, turborepo

I do have a mono repo that has a CLI package (`packages/cli`) and a web app (`apps/web`) and I'd like to consume the public API of the CLI within the web app.

The CLI package is bundled with tsup:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  clean: false,
  dts: true,
  entry: ["src/index.ts"],
  format: ["esm"],
  sourcemap: true,
  target: "esnext",
  outDir: "dist",
});
```

The `index.ts` is simply calling commander:

```js
(async () => {
  const program = new Command()
    .name("cli")
    .addCommand(info);

  program.parse();
})();
```

The `info` command is a simple Commander Command that prints some information:

```js
export function getInfo() {
  console.log("Hello there");
}

export const info = new Command().name("info").action(async () => {
  getInfo();
});
```

What I'd like to achieve now is to use `getInfo` within my web app - but how do I export it?

Putting a simple `export * from "./commands/info"` in my `index.ts` wouldn't work, since the entire CLI tool is automatically executed as soon as the `index.ts` of it is called.

I'm thinking of something like `import { getInfo } from "@pkg/cli/api"`, where I'd add a `api.ts` to my cli that's also exported - but how do I achieve this?

I tried to modify the `entry` of my `tsup` to `entry: ["src/index.ts", "src/api.ts"]`, where my `api.ts` simply exports the `getInfo` function. But my IDE suggests the `getInfo` import comes from `@pkg/cli/dist/api` - which doesn't work due to `Package path ./dist/api is not exported from package`.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Do you want it published to npm? Or why can't you just import it from "./commands/info"?

Comment: The CLI will be published, the web app will be just a website. `./commands/info` doesn't exist in the web app, it's in another project in the mono repo

Comment: Can you share your package.json, please. I don't quite understand how you published your CLI tool, if you already have, or how you intend to do so? As of my understanding, CLI expose their executable via the "bin" key in the package.json. So the "main" field could be used for your `api` build. If that's not helpful for some reason, look into the ["exports"](https://medium.com/swlh/npm-new-package-json-exports-field-1a7d1f489ccf) field in package.json. This way, you could probably resolve the problem described in your last paragraph, although I am not 100% sure what the issue is exactly.

Comment: The `main` field helped to get the imports working - unfortunately I now receive build warnings: "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression". These seem to originate from the fact that I'm using libs within the CLI that use `require`.

Comment: I need more details to resolve this issue. Does it happen when using the bin entry point? Did it work before? How did you export it before? Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42924147/10226440?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a new entrypoint to your CLI package. This will result in two total entries - one that can be executed as a binary (your CLI) and one that can be imported by other packages.

To set this up:

1. Create two files in your CLI package. One for the CLI entrypoint (this already exists as `src/index.ts`, but I would recommend renaming to `src/cli.ts` for clarity), and a second for the node api entrypoint: `src/index.ts`
2. The new `index.ts` file can just re-export the functions that you would like to expose publicly:

```
export { getInfo } from "./commands/info";
```

3. Update your `tsup` config to generate two entrypoints:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  clean: false,
  dts: true,
  // add both entrypoints here:
  entry: ["src/index.ts", "src/cli.ts"],
  format: ["esm"],
  sourcemap: true,
  target: "esnext",
  outDir: "dist",
});
```

4. Update your package.json with the new entrypoints

```
  "bin": "dist/cli.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

Now, the `bin` entrypoint will be used when executed directly, and the index `main` / `module` entrypoint will be used when imported by another module.